# issue with aws cli on wsl2 (windows subsystem for Linux)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, aws

I am using wsl2 on windows 10, but I am unable to access some eks features through AWS cli. I have credentials set on the windows system and everything works. I installed aws cli on wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 and can correctly execute some commands e.g.

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

but when trying to interact with eks cluster as shown below, it times out.

```
aws eks list-clusters
```

When executing this on the Windows terminal, it works just fine.

I checked the aws config file both under windows and wsl and it looks the same.

Any idea why is that?